# Case Label Value has already appeared Error

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

I'm writing some code to support some Bluetooth technology, and I keep getting the same error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Ive tried moving the case statement around to other locations, but that doesn't seem to help, it always traces back to it.

```
static void ProjectZero_processApplicationMessage(pzMsg_t *pMsg)
{
    // Cast to pzCharacteristicData_t* here since it's a common message pdu type.
    pzCharacteristicData_t *pCharData = (pzCharacteristicData_t *)pMsg->pData;

    switch(pMsg->event)
    {
    //////////////////// error pointing here
             case APP_MSG_SC_TASK_ALERT:
                   processTaskAlert();
                   break;
          ///////////////////////////

      case HCI_BLE_HARDWARE_ERROR_EVENT_CODE:
          AssertHandler(HAL_ASSERT_CAUSE_HARDWARE_ERROR,0);
          break;

      case PZ_SERVICE_WRITE_EVT: /* Message about received value write */
          /* Call different handler per service */
          switch(pCharData->svcUUID)
          {
            case LED_SERVICE_SERV_UUID:
                ProjectZero_LedService_ValueChangeHandler(pCharData);
                break;
            case DATA_SERVICE_SERV_UUID:
                ProjectZero_DataService_ValueChangeHandler(pCharData);
                break;
          }
          break;
    ///////Error occurs here, says its in the line below and then points to the line above 
      case PZ_SERVICE_CFG_EVT: /* Message about received CCCD write */
          /* Call different handler per service */
```

The error I keep receiving is below.
"../Application/project_zero.c", line 1148: error #1851: case label value has already appeared in this switch at line 1126

Comment: The code was running properly until I added that first case statement

Comment: `APP_MSG_SC_TASK_ALERT` probably expands to the same thing as 
`PZ_SERVICE_CFG_EVT`.

Comment: Replace the macros with their values, then review the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

> line 1148: error #1851: case label value has already appeared in this switch at line 1126

This means that you have you have more than one case in the switch with the same value. This is not allowed, hence the error.

From the error we can deduce that `APP_MSG_SC_TASK_ALERT` and `PZ_SERVICE_CFG_EVT` have the same value.